# the question about inequality of $L^p$norm and cut-off function

Tags: inequality

There is a Lemma that:

if $1 \leq p \leq +\infty,||f||_p$ for $ \alpha \in [p,+\infty],\rho > 1 $ satisfies  $ (H_{\alpha}^{\rho}) $,with$ A_{\alpha}(\rho)=(1-1/{\rho})^{1-1/{\rho}} < 1 $。especially，if $ 0 <p < 1,||f||_p $for all $ \alpha \in [p,+\infty],\rho > 1 $ satisfies $ (H_{\alpha}^{\rho}) $,with $$
   A_{\alpha}(\rho)=(1+(\rho - 1)^p / (\rho^p - 1))^{1/p}\wedge \rho(\rho - 1)/(\rho^p - 1)^{1/p}
   .$$
where$ W $ satisfies $ H_{\alpha}^{\rho} $ means that if there exists a constant $ A_{\alpha}(\rho) $,so that  for all $ f \in \mathcal{F}, $
 \begin{equation*}
 \left( \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}W(f_{\rho,k})^{\alpha} \right)^{1/ \alpha} \leq A_{\alpha}(\rho)W(f) 
 \end{equation*}
and $f_{\rho,k}=(f-\rho^k)^+ \wedge \rho^k(\rho - 1).$

**Here is the proof for the case of $1 \leq p \leq +\infty$**:

fix $ \rho > 1 $,write
  $$
   ||f_k||_p^p=p\int_{0}^{\rho^{k+1}-\rho^k} t^{p-1}\mu(f-\rho^k \ge t)dt=p\int_{\rho^k}^{\rho^{k+1}} (s-\rho^k)^{p-1}\mu(f\ge s)ds.
   $$

if $ 1\le p \le +\infty $,it follows that
   \begin{align*}
   \sum\limits_k||f_k||_p^p &= p\sum\limits_k\int_{\rho^k}^{\rho^{k+1}} (s-\rho^k)^{p-1}\mu(f\ge s)ds\\
   & \leq \left[ \sup_k \sup_{s\in [\rho^k,\rho^{k+1}]} \left( \frac{s-\rho^k}{s} \right)^{p-1} \right] \left[ p\sum_k\int_{\rho^k}^{\rho^{k+1}} s^{p-1}\mu(f\ge s)ds \right]
   & \le (1-1/\rho)^{p-1}||f||_p^p
   \end{align*}

**Here is the question:What I can't solve is the second case with $0 < p < 1,$waiting for help~**

Comment: Note that $\| \|_p$ is not a norm for $p<1$. Try the triangle inequality. But this isn't math overflow material. try stack exchange

Comment: But we can concern $||\cdot||_p$ as a quasi-norm for $p < 1$, just making use of its form.If you've got the idea,I'll be appreciated for your clear suggestion.